# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity $1$. An element $a \in R$ is called to be nilpotent if $a^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity $1$. An element $a \in R$
is called *nilpotent* if $a^n = 0$ for some positive integer $n$.

1. Prove that if $a, b$ are nilpotent, then so is $a + b$.
2. Prove that $H = \{ 1 − a \mid a \in R \text{ nilpotent} \}$
   is a group under the multiplication.
3. Suppose $R$ is finite with $\left|R\right| = N$. Prove that if $a \in R$ is nilpotent, then $(1 − a)^N = 1$.

For the first one I have :

> Suppose $a^m = 0$ and $b^n = 0$ and $k = m + n$. Then $(a+b)^k = c_0a^k + c_1a^{k-1}b + \cdots + c_n a^{k-n}b^n + \ldots$. All elements starting with $c_n$ will have $b^n  = 0$ as a factor and hence be $0$. Smallest power of $a$ is $k-n+1 \ge m$, as $k \ge m+n-1$. Then every term is of the form 
>   $c_ia^{k-i}b^i = c_i \cdot 0 = 0$. Every term is zero, so $(a+b)^k = 0$.

Second one:

> $(1-a)(1 + a + a^2+ \cdots +a^{n-1}) =  1-a^n = 1$ => Inverse = $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}$
>   identity = $1-a^n = 1$

I think the first one is correct but the second not. Could someone help me with the second and third one? Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Also, write $(a + b)^{n + m}$ for 1). You did not specify what $k$ is in your proof.

Comment: Sorry I forgot it^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In point 1. make $k$ concrete as $k = n+m$ (which will work, mostly for the reasons you discussed).

You are right that $(1 + a + \ldots + a^{n-1})$ is the inverse of the element $1-a$. Is this element of the form $1-b$ for some nilpotent $b$? (it should be in $H$). Here 1. will help, plus the observation that the powers of nilpotent elements are also nilpotent.

Also, you need to show that $H$ is closed under the operation multiplication, so note that $(1-a)(1-b) = 1 - (a + b) + ab = 1 - ((a+b) - ab)$. Is $(a+b) - ab$ nilpotent?

Nr 3. would be clear if $|H|$ would be a divisor of $N$. Is this true?